# Fabricjs object selection padding around text objects is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

When setting `padding` property as 0 in `fabricjs` object, it is working as intended on images but not on text objects as seen below:

[image]

For both the objects in the above image, `padding` property is 0 but the rendering is different on images and text. How to make `padding` property work correctly for text objects? Tested on `fabricjs` version `3.0.0`